# Snowflake How to Query Servername

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does Snowflake have anything in the information schema (or elsewhere) where I can query the servername of the server I am actively connected to?

I am developing in a BI tool that connects to a Snowflake data warehouse. I am seeing some anomalies in the data. Although my connection properties are supposedly pointing me to one server & database, I am not convinced that is where the data is actually coming from. I'd like to query Snowflake in the BI tool.

I've already checked the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES through the BI tool, and the database name is correct. I'd like to also verify the servername as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in information schema you can find on the actual underlying resources you are connected too. From the documentation:

> The data objects stored by Snowflake are not directly visible nor accessible by customers; they are only accessible through SQL query operations run using Snowflake.

But I doubt that is what is causing the anomaly. In snowflake the data is coming from Cloud Storage. There is a clear seperation of compute & storage. A virtual warehouse in snowflake is essentially a query execution engine. So even if you connect to a different server that should not matter in terms of what the query returns.

See also: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html#database-storage.

Comment: Perhaps "server" was the wrong word. Basically, I am working with multiple Snowflake "instances". For example:

https://my_snowflake_1.us-east.snowflakecomputing.com --  https://my_snowflake_2.us-east.snowflakecomputing.com -- 
https://my_snowflake_3.us-east.snowflakecomputing.com -- 

Each has a different set of databases/warehouses/etc. So while my BI connection properties are allegedly set to "my_snowflake_1", I want to make sure that is actually what it is connected to and pulling data from. I am trying to rule out any connection property errors on my end. TY

Comment: Do you use the same credentials for all instances? Because otherwise the fact that you are connected to that URL should already be a good enough indication right?

Comment: Not when the BI tool is using a dynamic, per-user, variable for the Snowflake connection parameters. If there is a simple way to query the Snowflake "instance" name, I could do that in a matter of seconds in the BI tool just to verify the connection, and provide a little extra direction on where to look for the problem. Work smarter, not harder.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

- [`CURRENT_ACCOUNT()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_account.html)
- [`CURRENT_REGION()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_region.html)

But you may have to do a bit of work to convert the region to the format expected in the url (maybe create a mapping or a UDF). For example, `AWS_US_EAST_1` would need to be converted to `us-east-1`.